# git read-tree to project root

Tags: git, merge

I have my main_repo with folder structure like this

application_root

- app
- - code
- - - foo
- - - - file1
- - - - file2
- - - bar
- skin
- lib
- file1
- file2

It's the main application. And I have another repo with an extension for my main application. The problem is that extension directory layout overlap directories from the root of main project such as

extension_root

- app
- - code
- - - baz
- - - - file1
- - - - file2
- skin
- - file1
- - file2
- file3
- file4

So I can't use submodule tool. I need to merge this two repositories for farther development. I need the ability to merge from extension_repo to main_repo and back as well so if I made changes to my extension which was merged to main_repo I can merge only this changes (without application itself) to extension_repo.
I don't know if it even possible. It seems that read-tree merging do what I want but I can't use it in such way

```
git read-tree --prefix=/ -u extension_remote_branch
```

because I get this error

```
error: Entry '.gitignore' overlaps with '.gitignore'.  Cannot bind.
```

I guess I'll get this error for all directories I have overlaped. I don't actually have overlaped files except of .gitignore.

Comment: Well, git doesn't care about directories, so if `.gitignore` is your only conflict you'll probably be fine if you can deal with that.

Comment: Ok, I deleted .gitignore from main_repo and then read-tree merged extension_remote_branch to my main_repo, but then I made some changes to extension files, checkout to extension branch and try to merge -s subtree it deleted all files of my extension. Strange...

Answer (score 8):

So far I haven't found a way to do this in a single command via git; so instead I use a fairly straightforward workaround.  The basic approach is to `read-tree` into a second, empty directory.  Then move the second directory overtop the first.

The basic flow is:

```
mkdir upstream-tree
git read-tree --prefix=upstream-tree/ -u myremote/branch
git commit -m "Pulled in remote tree"
cp -rf upstream-tree/* local-tree/
git rm -r upstream-tree
git add local-tree
git commit -m "Merged upstream-tree into local-tree"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess. You are magento developer?

For now I found a solution:

- Clone your extention repo
- Add remote of clean framework(magento in my case),
- `git merge -s ours --no-commit ...`
- read-tree from framework repo and reset index

Now all changes will be saved to the extension's repo. Without framework's files. Unfortunatly this method only works for one extension. 
But I saw an interesting way with renaming of `.git` folders for each extension. I Have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Check your index - if you had been "trying" to `git read-tree` but took a few stabs at it before you got the syntax correct, you could have a bunch of changes in your index that aren't showing up causing the conflict.

I hit this exact scenario today trying to `read-tree` an existing project into the root of an empty (new) git repo - the `git read-tree --prexfix=/ -u BRANCH` worked perfectly after I `reset` and `clean`d my `master` branch.

Answer (score 1):

As workaround you can do `read-tree` into different folder then move it back, something like:

```
git remote add foo git@example.com/foo.git
git fetch foo
git reset
git read-tree --prefix=new/ -u foo/master:/
git mv new/* .
rsync -vuar --delete-after new/ .
rm -fr new
```